# Heroku Rails server API not setting the correct port number when starting up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

I have a Rails API Backend with a React front end that is deployed to Heroku. When I try to load a page that makes a call to the API, it hangs and then finally gives this error in the console:

```
GET https://MYAPP.herokuapp.com:3001/auth/refresh_token net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

When I look at the logs while the application is starting up, it looks as though I'm setting the port to `3001` which is what I want but it looks as those puma is listening on a different port number:

```
2020-10-01T04:28:51.720203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3001} -e ${RACK_ENV:-production}`
2020-10-01T04:28:55.321298+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2020-10-01T04:28:55.321325+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2020-10-01T04:28:55.321326+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2020-10-01T04:28:55.321326+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2020-10-01T04:29:04.625683+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:55912
```

Should I be configuring my fetches to use this URL instead?: `https://MYAPP.herokuapp.com/auth/refresh_token`

Basically, what I'm asking is: Based on this log information where is my Rails API listening if my React application is listening at: `https://MYAPP.herokuapp.com`?

Comment: have you tried to call it without any port?

Comment: @kimpastro that worked. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the chosen answer.